# What is the syntax error I am making?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

noob here im hitting a syntax error in Python3 and am unsure how to correct it.

```
File "assign1.py", line 24
    print(chr(code))
        ^
number = ord('C')
number = ord('a') + (number << 8)
number = ord('t') + (number << 8)

print(bin(number))

code = number  >> (6 * 3)
number = number - (code  << (6 * 3))
code = number >> (6 * 2)
number = number - (code  << (6 * 3))
code = number >> (6 * 1)
number = number - (code << (6 * 1)

print(chr(code))
```

Comment: can you post your error trace ?

Comment: What is the syntax error that you are hitting?

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis on the line before it.

Comment: Please use an IDE that warns you about problems like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a closing parethensis, aka `)`, in the following sentence:

```
number = number - (code << (6 * 1)
```